# What is the equivalent to addForce()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add an Impulse force on my character controller... Normally, if you had a rigidbody, you could do something like rb.addForce(Vector3.down, ForceMode.Impulse) and end the code. But I am not sure how to implement this same thing for a character controller. P.S. I want to have a downward force added on my character controller only once... (I am not sure if this will help but, when I crouch my player floats middair. I want to add a downward force so that the player will touch the ground.)

I surfed through the internet and found no solutions. I tried using Move() but it does not apply the force in an impulse manner. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

just apply velocity to your rigidbody for walk or run,for an impulse, like a jump or a knockback, Make sure you are not applying a speed (even if it is zero) in X, Y or Z axes in Update(), FixedUpdates() or a class inside Update()

Comment: I am not using a rigidbody... If I am right, you cannot use rigidbody with Character Controller. So, If you have any other solutions, Please tell.

Comment: probably a Vector3.MoveTowards, but you should use a rogidbody.

more info -> https://www.w3schools.blog/unity-movetowards

Comment: It does not really work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).